# Optimize out of memory error with groupby object

Tags: python, optimization, memory, group-by

How to optimize memory usage when running a code on an HPC with a large dataset of 70GB and a pandas group by data of 1616187757 rows × 2 columns? The code is currently returning an out of memory error. The code performs ROC curve computation. Here is the current data set excerpt before groupby function (multi indexed data with p1 and p2).

```
        corr    corum
p1  p2      
AHNAK   PLEC    0.674011    0
FLNA    0.738518    0
MYH11   0.698690    0
TLN1    0.592942    0
MYH9    0.390184    0
... ... ... ...
ZYG11B  ZZEF1   0.280679    0
ZZZ3    0.401258    0
ZYX ZZEF1   0.175223    0
ZZZ3    0.157843    0
ZZEF1   ZZZ3    0.153653    0
1616187757 rows × 2 columns
```

And this is the implementation of the code.

```
 # Import libraries
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    import pickle
    import re
    import scipy.sparse as sp
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
    from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
    from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
    from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
    from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score
    from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
    from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
    from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge
    
    # Setting working directory
    relative_path = "data"
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), relative_path)
    
    # Functions neeeded
    # Step 1) Function for computing correlation matrix
    def compute_corr(df):
        return df.transpose().corr(method = 'pearson', min_periods = 30)
    
    # Step 2) Function for converting corr_matrix to the list (code implemented fro$
    def mat_to_list(df):
        upper_tria = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape),1).astype('bool').reshape(df.size)
        correl = df.stack(dropna=False)[upper_tria].dropna()
        return(correl)
    
    # Step 3) Function for resetting the index name and add corum column
    def reset_index(df):
        df = df.rename_axis(['p1', 'p2']).reset_index()
        df = df.rename(columns= {df.columns[2]: "corr"})
        df['corum'] = 0
        df = df.set_index(['p1', 'p2'])[['corr', 'corum']]
        return(df)
    
    # Step 4) Function for substituting the corum column to 1 if the matches exist
    def find_match_corum(df):
        df.loc[df.index.isin(corum_index), 'corum'] = 1
        return(df)
    
    # Function for sorting the rows with the corr mat only without imputations
    def common_index_pairs(df, index):
        common_index = df.index.isin(index)
        return(df.loc[common_index])
    
    # Function to compute the ROC curve and AUC value
    def compute_roc(df):
        # Define the target variable and predicted probabilities
        y_true = df['corum']
        y_pred = df['corr']
    
        # Compute the false positive rate, true positive rate, and thresholds for d$
        fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred)
    
        # Plot the ROC curve
        plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
        plt.title('ROC Curve')
    
        # Compute the AUC value
        auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)
        print('AUC:', auc)
    
    
    with open(f'prob_group.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            prob_group = pickle.load(f)
    
    def calculate_new_prob(group):
        new_prob = 1 - np.product(1 - group['corr'])
        group['corr'] = new_prob
        return group
    
    prob_group = prob_group.apply(calculate_new_prob)
    
    with open(f'prob_method2.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(prob_group, f)
    
    compute_roc(prob_group)
```